# whats the supremum of (a) 2/-n^2: n E Z (b)cosx

Tags: calculus

I believe that the supremum of (a) is 1 since anything above this will result in a non integer and for part (b) im thinking its 1 since its the upper bound of cosx: E R.  Is this correct in the way im approaching and if not how should I approach it?

Comment: For a), can you tell me a value of $n$ such that the fraction is bigger than $\frac12$? If you can't (which you can't), that would imply your supremum is incorrect.

Comment: why must I get a value for n so that the fraction is bigger than 1/2? if the supremum was 1 would the fraction not equal 2 and be greater than 1/2?

Comment: Do you know what the definition of supremum is? Mind writing it here so that I see that you know the correct definition?

Comment: Isn't the supremum of a set its least upper bound?

Comment: Ok, then if there isn't a value of $n$ for which the fraction is above $\frac12$, wouldn't you say $\frac12$ is an upper bound? How is 1 the least upper bound?

Answer (score 1):

The supremum of { 2/(-n$^2$) : n in Z } is 0.
The supremum of { 2 - 1/n$^2$ : n in Z } is 2.
The supremum of { 2/-n$^2$ : n in Z }, one could suppose, is 0.

cos x does not have a supremum because it just a number;  it is not a set.
The supremum of A = { cos x : x in R } is 1.
What is the infinum of A?  Does A have a maximum? A mininum?
What is the supremum of B = { cos x : 0 < x < $\pi$/4 }?
What is the infinum of B?  Does B have a maximum? A mininum?

Comment: But for {2/-n^2 :n in Z}if I was to set n=-1 I would get a value of 2. Would this not be the upper bound and also the least upper bound. There is no value for n that can give me a greater number then 2 which is why I think its an upper bound. where am I going wrong.

Comment: For the questions you asked would the infimum of cosx : x in R be -1 if x were to be 180 and -1 also be its minimum? And for the last question would 0 be the infimum and pi/4 be the supremum with it having no maximum of minimum value.